# How to change color of specific datagridrow by press of a button

Tags: c#, datatable, colors, row

So basically I have a data table and I have a bunch of labels and text input boxes and when I want to save my inputted text into the data table I press the button 'save'. But I want to make it that when  press 'new' button (which allows me to be able to insert text into the textboxes which when saved is pressed will show in the `datatable`) I can also press 3 colors option buttons to set a specific color for the new `datatablerow` I just made. Or another option is that when I highlight a `datatablerow` I can then press a button to change the row color.

I have this code right now:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
    {
        row.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Red;
        row.DefaultCellStyle.ForeColor = Color.White;
    }
}
```

But when pressed it sets all rows to the color red, I only want it to do it to the ones I highlight...

I hope anyone can help :)

Comment: instead of `dataGridView1.Rows` you need to use `dataGridView1.SelectedRows`

Comment: The grid’s `DefaultCellStyle`  has properties to change the “selection” style… `SelectionBackColor` and `SelectionForeColor`.

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya Thank you!!!!!!!

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya edit: wait nvm, it does work, so i would select a row and press 'green button' and it would make the row green, then i have a 'save' button to save the changes and close the app, when i press save it resets the colour change and goes back to white... this ONLY occurs when i press save and i need to press  save. any ideas?

Comment: No idea.... You can ask a different question for that issue with all the relevant details and code